# How to add the columns after subseting?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have the following data frame:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

dic = {
    "ID": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    "Age": [18, 20, 18, 30, 30],
    "Car": ["BMW", "Benz", "BMW", "porsche", "porsche"],
    "Salary": [1000, 2000, 3000, 1200, 4000]
}

dt = pd.DataFrame(dic)
```

I need to omit the rows, which has duplicated values on  `Age` and `Car`. I can subset and remove the duplicate as below:

```
dt = dt.iloc[:, np.r_[1:3]].drop_duplicates()
```

However, the issue is I need to keep `Salary` and `ID` for the remaining column!

I am wondering, what is the easiest way to add, (or keep `ID` and `Salary`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `drop_duplicates` like this:

```
dt.drop_duplicates(['Age', 'Car'], keep = 'first')
```

Output:

```
   ID  Age      Car  Salary
0   1   18      BMW    1000
1   2   20     Benz    2000
3   4   30  porsche    1200
```

Comment: Could you please explain the `keep` option?

Comment: keep = 'first' (also default) means you keep the first occurence and delete all other duplicates that follow. keep = 'last' means, you keep the last record and delete the rest; you will have ID 3 for BMW and not 1. And keep = False, just removes all duplicate records and doesnt keep anything that is a duplicate.

Comment: Your output looked like you wanted to keep the first instances and delete the rest. Hence, added that.

Comment: So, when i do not have `keep` on my code, then what is the default? and why i do not have the rest?

Comment: Default is keep = 'first'. You are not getting the rest of the columns because you are performing the subset like this: `dt.iloc[:,np.r_[1:3] ]` <- which gives only two columns, Age and Car, and you are now passing only two columns to drop_duplicates. What you need to do is tell drop_duplicates, "hey, remove duplicates from the combination AGE and CAR", then it just does that keeps all your other columns intact. Like the code I have posted.

Comment: Understood. Is there any way that, i can use index of column instead of `['Age', 'Car']`?  for example something like `[1,2]`?

Comment: You can reverse it like this: `dt.drop_duplicates(dt.iloc[:,np.r_[1:3] ].columns.tolist(), keep = 'first')` :)

Answer (score 0):

If I got you right, you want to delete only the Age and the Car combinations that already appear in the table, but keep the values of the ID and the Salary.
In that case, you should use:

```
drops = dt[['Age', 'Car']].duplicated()
dt['Age'][drops] = np.nan
dt['Car'][drops] = np.nan
```

If I didn't understand you right, comment and I'll delete this answer.